# Change date format in Django admin page

Tags: django

When i export the data from my admin page to excel it is giving default date format.But I need to change the default date format(2018-10-18) to (10/18/2018) in admin page.Where should i change this?

**models.py**

```
class Track(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Not in the *model*. A model is about *storing* values, not about *representing* these...

Comment: so where should i do this? i am completely beginner

Comment: in the `ModelAdmin` of the model.

Comment: you mean in admin.py?

Comment: as you marked this as duplicate may i get the link which has answer?

Comment: it is at the top...